# How to select a face closest to a point in space?

Tags: python, modeling, scripting, selection-tools, 3d-cursor

I use cursor depth to snap the 3d cursor on my object. I want select the face corresponding the 3d cursor. There is a tricks with Blender python API ?

Exemple (Before/After) :

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]
Try this (requires you to have one selected and active mesh object):

```
import bpy

cur = bpy.context.scene.cursor_location
o   = bpy.context.object

bpy.ops.object.mode_set( mode = 'OBJECT' )
faceIdx = o.closest_point_on_mesh( cur )[-1]

if faceIdx != -1:
    o.data.polygons[ faceIdx ].select = True

bpy.ops.object.mode_set( mode = 'EDIT' )
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you cannot select a face with the 3D cursor, but <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> > *Cursor to selected* will put it at the center of the face or face group... I think this is what you're asking. Also <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> has other settings for direct placement in relation to 3D cursor. they are named

- Cursor to grid
- Cursor to center (origin)

they do exactly what they sound like.

Comment: I know these shortcuts. This is not what I want. I will see bpy_extras.view3d_utils.location_3d_to_region_2d(region, rv3d, coord)